# What's the general declension for neuter words ending in -е?

Tags: відмінювання, іменники, declension

Ok,so I have been making a list of genders and their changeable endings and I have found no reliable sources concerning the declension of these words. Some show -я and others -а. To avoid guessing again using a thousand words and putting them through Google translate I will just expect an answer here. ^^

Comment: Probably you should have put more efforts in searching for the answer in the internet and studding Ukrainian grammar. Here is an article on your subject. [Відмінювання іменників ІІ відміни середнього роду](http://studopedia.org/12-57244.html). Check words `поле` (singular) & `поля`(plural). As for me your question is too wide.

Answer (score 2):

[Nouns of neutral gender may belong either to the second or to the fourth declension](http://ukrainiangrammar.com/article/2011-01-25/the-noun-declensions.html)

[Here you can find an example](http://ukrainiangrammar.com/article/2011-01-26/the-noun-second-declension.html) of declension

Neuter nouns

```
Case            Singular                    Plural
Nominative      море        обличчя         моря        обличчя
Genitive        моря        обличчя         морів       облич∅
Dative          морю        обличчю         морям       обличчям
Accusative      море        обличчя         моря        обличчя
Instrumental    морем       обличчям        морями      обличчями
Locative        (на) морі   (на) обличчі    (на) морях  (на) обличчях
Vocative        море        обличчя         моря        обличчя
```

море ['mɔrɛ] — a sea
[image: Neuter nouns]